# URPでポストエフェクトかけるスクリプトのエラー

Tags: c#

URPでポストエフェクトをかけるスクリプトをUnity公式から自分のプロジェクトに持ってはきたけれども、Blit関数でエラーが出てしまう。
いくら探しても同じコードでいけているのでなぜエラーが出てしまっているのかわからなくて困っています。

```
public override void Execute
  (ScriptableRenderContext context, ref RenderingData data)
{
    if (material == null) return;
    var cmd = CommandBufferPool.Get("PostEffect");
    Blit(cmd, ref data, null, material, 0);　　　　　　
    context.ExecuteCommandBuffer(cmd);
    CommandBufferPool.Release(cmd);
}
```

}

ここのBlit関数で　"引数２はキーワード"ref"と共に返すことはできせん" とエラーが発生してしまいます。エラーの対処法はありますでしょうか？

Comment: 参考にしたUnity公式のスクリプトのURLがわかれば、回答しやすくなるかもしれません。またエラーそのものはBlitメソッドの第2引数にrefが使えないというものなので、Blitメソッドの呼び出し方が誤っているように見えます。

Comment: お手数おかけします。参考動画はこちらです。⇒　https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E_oDKQU3e94&t=800s　　スクリプト自体はこちらhttps://github.com/keijiro/SimplePostEffects/tree/main/Assets/PostEffect　のPosteffectFeature.csになります。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URPのバージョンが古いのではないでしょうか。
7.1.8では該当しそうな[Blitメソッド](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@7.1/api/UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal.ScriptableRenderPass.html#UnityEngine_Rendering_Universal_ScriptableRenderPass_Blit_CommandBuffer_RenderTargetIdentifier_RenderTargetIdentifier_Material_System_Int32_)は存在していませんが、
13.1.9ではそれらしい[Blitメソッド](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@13.1/api/UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal.ScriptableRenderPass.html#UnityEngine_Rendering_Universal_ScriptableRenderPass_Blit_UnityEngine_Rendering_CommandBuffer_UnityEngine_Rendering_Universal_RenderingData__UnityEngine_Material_System_Int32_)が存在しています。
一度URPを最新のバージョンに上げて試してみてください。

Comment: Versionを10.10.0から13.15.1まで上げたところ、エラーが消え、解決に至りました！